# Prove that there exists a delta > zero such that.....

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\lim_{z \to z_0} g(z) = B \not= 0$. Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$|g(z)| > \frac{|B|}{2} \textrm{ for $0 <|z - z_0| < \delta $.}$$

I have had several attempts at this proof. I'm not sure how to answer this. It seems very complicated.

Comment: Are you sure it is $\gt$ and not $\lt$ ??

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest writing out the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of your limit, and then choosing the *right* $\varepsilon$...

Answer (score 2):

You can select $\delta$ so that $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - B| < \dfrac{|B|}{2}$. Now play with the triangle inequality to find that $|g(x)| > \dfrac{|B|}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $\epsilon = \frac{|B|}{2}$. By definition of limits, $\exists \delta>0$ such that for $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, $|lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)-g(z)|<\epsilon=\frac{|B|}{2}$.

Then for $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$,

$|lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)|-|g(z)| \leq |lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)-g(z)|<\frac{|B|}{2}$

$|g(z)|> |lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)|-\frac{|B|}{2}=\frac{|B|}{2}$

Comment: How does this show that there exists a delta more than zero? Also, why have you chosen this epsilon?

Comment: Review the definition of limits, for every epsilon>0 such a delta>0 exists. As for why this epsilon is chosen... well, it's a skill to be picked up...